# Running Homekit Home Hub and an autonomous single mode app at the same time in an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, homekit

Can I run Homekit Home Hub and an app in Autonomous Single App Mode enabled on an iPad? The app will be a client to the Home Hub. I suspected that there will be no problem. Just want to confirm.

Comment: Have you tested it by now?

Comment: My understanding now is, HomeKit does not have a hub, it is a configuration that passing around through a configuration file in iCloud. Therefore, any device having that configuration file could interact with any devices configured in the configuration file.

Comment: Makes sense, but there must be at least a small part that sends notifications to the user and handles the automation (HMEvent et al.)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc18/231 gives (again) a good overview.